# Android crash when use context with two different plugins using Nativescript. Convert m4a to wav

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, nativescript, android-context

Currently I'm using two plugins inside my Nativescript App for android, this 
[nativescript-audio](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio) for recording audio and this  [AndroidAudioConverter](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/cafe/adriel/androidaudioconverter/AndroidAudioConverter.java) for convert the audio to .wav format. The problem is after converting the audio file to wav the **context** in android loss a method **getSystemService** (just sometimes) and when I record another audio and try to play it doesn't sound. After converting an audio if I shut down the application I get multiple errors.

This error when I try to play the audio after converting an audio

```
error playFromFile TypeError: ctx.getSystemService is not a function
```

When I play it If I don't convert the audio this does not happen.

This error happen when I to press the back button to exit the application or shut down the application to background after converting an audio :

```
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {xxxxxxxx/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onStop failed
System.err: TypeError: getApplication(...).getApplicationContext is not a function
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.js, line: 59, column: 50
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'getApplicationContext', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.js', line: 59, column: 51
System.err:     Frame: function:'getInputMethodManager', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.js', line: 87, column: 34
System.err:     Frame: function:'dismissSoftInput', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.js', line: 100, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'EditableTextBase.dismissSoftInput', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/editable-text-base/editable-text-base.js', line: 147, column: 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'EditableTextBase.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/editable-text-base/editable-text-base.js', line: 139, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 92
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 304, column: 9
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.unloadView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 444, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 246, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js', line: 125, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 868, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 245, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'View.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 235, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 92
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 304, column: 9
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.unloadView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 444, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 246, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'ContentView.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view/content-view.js', line: 70, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'PageBase.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page-common.js', line: 120, column: 40
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 868, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 245, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'View.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 235, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 92
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 304, column: 9
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.unloadView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 444, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 246, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'FrameBase.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 368, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 868, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 245, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'View.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 235, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'Frame.onUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 158, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 92
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 304, column: 9
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase.callUnloaded', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 315, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onStop', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 780, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onStop', file:'file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js', line: 33, column: 25
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3870)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onStop failed
System.err: TypeError: getApplication(...).getApplicationContext is not a function
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/xxxxxxxx/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/utils.js, line: 59, column: 50
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:
```

To install AndroidAudioConverter I create a plugin with this dependencies in the gradle file:

```
repositories {
   maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
   compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'
}
```

To record an audio I use this code:

```
 const recorder = new audio.TNSRecorder();
 const player = new audio.TNSPlayer();  

_recordAudio: function () {
    console.log("_recordAudio")
    var ext = ".m4a"
    _this = this
    var path = audioFolder.path + "/audio" + new Date().getMilliseconds() + ext;
    _this.RECORDING_PATH = path
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var androidFormat = null;
        var androidEncoder = null;
        if (platform.isAndroid) {
            androidFormat = 2; 
            androidEncoder = 3; 
        }
        var recorderOptions = {
            filename: path,
            format: androidFormat,
            bitRate: 24000,
            source: 1,
            encoder: androidEncoder,
            sampleRate: 16000,
            metering: false,
            infoCallback: function (audio) {
                console.log("infoCallback recordAudio");
            },
            errorCallback: function (err) {
                console.log("errorCallback recordAudio");
                alert("Error recording.", err);
            }
        };
        recorder.start(recorderOptions).then(function (audio) {
            console.log("recorder.start");
            return resolve(audio);
        },function(err){
            return reject(err)
          })
    });
}
```

To convert an audio I use this code: **EDITED FOR IMPLEMENT INTERFACES CORRECTLY**

```
convertMp4ToWav: function (filePath) {
var _this = this
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var result = {
        code: -1,
        message: ""
    }
    var cleanPromiseVariablesAndroid = function () {
        _this.resolveConvertMp4ToWav = null
        _this.rejectConvertMp4ToWav = null
        _this.file = null
    }
    _this.resolveConvertMp4ToWav = resolve
    _this.rejectConvertMp4ToWav = reject
    if (!filePath || typeof filePath != "string") {
        result.message = "No input file"
        return reject(result)
    }
    var file = new java.io.File(filePath)
    _this.file = file
    var context = _this.getAndroidContext()
    if (!context) {
        result.message = "Error converting file"
        return reject(result)
    }
    var IConvertCallback = cafe.adriel.androidaudioconverter.callback.IConvertCallback.extend({
        onSuccess: function (fileCoverted) {
            try {
                console.log("callbackConvert onSuccess")
                var newPath = fileCoverted.getPath()
                result.code = 1
                result.path = newPath
                result.message = "File converted"
                _this.resolveConvertMp4ToWav(result)
                cleanPromiseVariablesAndroid();
                return
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("callbackConvert catch")
                console.error(e);
                result.message = "Error converting file"
                _this.rejectConvertMp4ToWav(result)
                cleanPromiseVariablesAndroid();
                return
            }
        },
        onFailure: function (err) {
            console.log(" callbackConvert onFailure")
            console.error(err);
            result.message = "Error converting file"
            _this.rejectConvertMp4ToWav(result)
            cleanPromiseVariablesAndroid();
            return
        }
    })
    var callbackConvert = new IConvertCallback();
    var ILoadCallback = cafe.adriel.androidaudioconverter.callback.ILoadCallback.extend({
        onSuccess: function () {
            console.log("callbackLoad onSuccess");
            var transcode = new cafe.adriel.androidaudioconverter.AndroidAudioConverter.with(context)
            transcode.setFile(_this.file)
            transcode.setFormat(cafe.adriel.androidaudioconverter.model.AudioFormat.WAV);
            transcode.setCallback(callbackConvert)
            transcode.convert();
        },
        onFailure: function (err) {
            console.log("callbackLoad onFailure");
            console.log(err)
            result.message = "Error converting file"
            _this.rejectConvertMp4ToWav(result)
            cleanPromiseVariablesAndroid();
            return
        }
    })
    var callbackLoad = new ILoadCallback()
    cafe.adriel.androidaudioconverter.AndroidAudioConverter.load(context, callbackLoad)
})
```

}

To play an audio I use this code:

```
 playFromFile: function (path) {
    console.log("playFromFile")
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var result = {
            code: -1,
            message: ""
        }
        var playerOptions = {
            audioFile: path,
            loop: false,
            completeCallback: function () {
                console.log("completeCallback");

            },
            errorCallback: function (errorObject) {
                console.log("errorCallback");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorObject));
            },
            infoCallback: function (args) {
                console.log("infoCallback");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
            }
        };
        player.playFromFile(playerOptions).then(function (res) {
                console.log("result  player.playFromFile")
                result.code = 1
                result.message = "Correct"
                return resolve(result)

            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("error playFromFile", err);
                result.message = "An error ocurred playing file"
                return reject(result)
            });
    })
}
```

To get the context:

```
 getAndroidContext: function () {
    var _this = this;
    var ctx = app.android.context
    if (!ctx) {
        ctx = app.getNativeApplication().getApplicationContext();
    }
    if (ctx === null) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            _this.getAndroidContext();
        }, 200);
        return;
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

The flow I follow is record an audio, play it, and convert it. It works perfectly once, the errors comes when I convert the audio.

Comment: Looks like your syntax for implementing interfaces is not correct. Please refer the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface#interfaces) and update your implementation. All the interface methods should be passed as key value pairs as the first argument to the JS constructor. In order to get context, you may simply use `app.android.context`.

Comment: I post  the function **getAndroidContext** incorrect, actually I use app.android.context to get the context, but the error is different. I am not using interfaces to add methods to the class AndroidAudioConverter.

Comment: Please update your code once you fix the interfaces. Also let me know when exactly you call `getAndroidContext`, if you call it after app launch just `app.android.context` should work.

Comment: @Manoj I didn't know about the implementations of interfaces java/nativescript, and one of my problem was the way to instance the objects, thanks for the answer. And to comment I notice when I use some variables in the interfaces  loss their scope. When I use resolve, reject method or file variable specifically, For that reason I need to save those variables in other way in order to use them inside interfaces.